VS Code chooses wrong Texlive version in second window although PATH is properly defined
I have two installations of Texlive: the newer "native" installation and an outdated "distro" installation. The first window of VS Code uses the "native" Texlive, all further windows use the "distro" installation. Why is that and how do I make all windows use the "native" installation?

Background info:
I recently installed "native" Texlive on because the packages that come with my Ubuntu distribution are a little outdated. For installation, I followed the official guide, so I added /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux to the beginning of the PATH variable via the ~/.bashrc file. The output of echo $PATH is /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux: ......... :/usr/bin: ........, where I replaced the unrelevant bits by dots.
Since the "native" Texlive installation should be preferred by the PATH arrangement, it should be used when I compile documents in VS Code. But this is the case only in the first VS Code window. When I open a second window of VS Code, the "distro" Texlive is used, that is provided with my Ubuntu installation. When I open a third window, it also uses the "distro" Texlive.
How do I know which Texlive is used? I can see it, when I look at the .log file created when compiling a document. It shows the location of the used Texlive installation.
Is the PATH changed in the second (third) window? I don't think so. At least not that I know. When I open the terminal inside VS Code, echo $PATH gives the same output in all windows and it is the same as I have written above.

Following the comments of @Dai Bowen and @daleif, I tried opening VS Code in different ways to see if it changes the outcome. I opend VS Code:

A: through app launcher
B: through file explorer by clicking the target folder, "open with">"VS Code"
C: through terminal
D: from within VS Code (File>New Window)
E: from taskbar icon ("New empty Window")
whereas D and E only apply for further windows.

It turns out that the "native" Texlive is chosen for the first window independently of how I open it (A, B or C).
But it matters for the second window! The "native" Texlive is chosen only for C and D. The other three methods will use the "distro" Texlive.
Can I change that behaviour so that "native" is chosen irrespective of the opening method?

It could be this issue although slightly odd if the PATH is correct on first opening. Are you launching the first window through the terminal? and subsequent windows through the GUI (either of the OS or VS Code)?

The solution Dai mentions is the standard solution when editors behave strangely. If they are opened in a context where .bashrc is never "seen" then setting PATH there is not enough

Thanks for your input. It turns out that the way of opening doesn't matter for the first window but does make a difference for further windows. I wrote the details of my further testing at the end of my original question. I'll try the solution @DaiBowen linked and report.

@DaiBowen it worked! Thank you so much and daleif too! If you don't mind, could you post this as an answer so I can accept it as a solution?

I'd probably mark it as a duplicate atm, there seems to be something extra going on from what you've described, but whatever it is setting .profile has resolved it. Right now, the exact behaviour could be down to any of the OS, VS Code, or plugins you're using.
